# I was unable to center text on left side

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="left"><div class="c">centrated<br>on<br>lef side</div></td>
<td>middle-td</td>
<td>right-td</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
td.left {
    width: 200px;
    left-padding: 0;
    }
div.c {
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Now everything is centered.
I want to place the div on left side and everything inside the div should be centered. I've tried everything that I can do but I was unable to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the float:left property on the div